# Dynamic sumif cell range to include all cells above active cell

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm looking for a way to identify ranges in a `sumif` formula in Google Sheets where the range includes all cells above the active cell.

I want my formula ranges to start at row 5 then count all cells below row 5 until either the active row or the criteria "Grand Total" so the `sumif` formula knows where the range ends. I'm trying:

```
=sumif(A5:A&match("Grand Total",A5:A,0),{"David Total","Jill Total"},F5:F&(match("Grand Total",A5:A,0)))
```

the match formula should result in the criteria range A5:A24 and sum range F5:F24  but I'm getting a message "argument must be a range".

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(
 INDIRECT("A5:A"&MAX(IF(A5:A="Grand Total", ROW(A5:A), ))),
 {"David Total", "Jill Total"},
 INDIRECT("F5:F"&MAX(IF(A5:A="Grand Total", ROW(A5:A), )))))
```

[image: 0]